# All of a sudden not working, using linked server to source getting "Communication link failure"

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, admin, jobs

These jobs were working then all of a sudden all jobs connecting to source server are getting "Communication link failure". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server .  We have tried same from another server to the source server and getting the same error.  We can see the linked server and the db and tables etc.
The error at the SQL level is:

```
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ServerName" returned message "Protocol error in TDS stream".
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ServerName" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg -1, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]. 
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ServerName" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg -1, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Session Provider: Physical connection is not usable [xFFFFFFFF]. 
OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "ServerName" returned message "Communication link failure".
Msg 10060, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Any T-SQL/Stored Procedure that does not have a large dataset works without issue.

The stored procedure [stored procedure] generates the same error; however it does not use this linked server, it uses a different one.

Troubleshooting so far:
•   IT Security verified traffic is allowed and see packets for both send and receive; nothing is being blocked

- The System’s verified no changes have been applied to either server
- Applications team verified no changes have been applied to servers
- Networking has verified that the only changes are firmware updates to the firewalls and that traffic is not being hindered.
- Ran the requested command to disable TCP Chimney (netsh int tcp set global chimney=disabled); generated the error: 'chimney' is not a valid argument for this command.
- These all generated the same error as above
- Running the stored procedure code as T-SQL
- Hard-coded linked server to use a different one
- Dropped and recreated the linked server connection
- Re-compiled the stored procedures

On 20 March 2024, the processes in question took an additional 8 hours to run; today (21 March2024) they are running for a while (sometimes 5 minutes, sometimes 1 hour) and generating this error.

The connection is used by multiple processes on server, only 6 are failing with this error.  The 6 that are failing are pulling data from the database "Databasename".

Comment: While you're debugging the problem, I suggest switching to a supported driver; SQLNCLI was deprecated in 2012 and reached EoL in 2014.

Comment: Maybe some windows update "improved" the odbc drivers?

Comment: Additional information, the server running the jobs  with stored procedures using the linked server is sql server 2014 sp3  the linked server is sql server 2019 cu17

Comment: so, you can access linked server if you run: `select * from linkedserver.master.sys.objects` on sql server 2014 but not when running via jobs?

Comment: Yes, that is correct jobs with stored procedure pulling large datasets.

Comment: Well, that's something else, the connection works, but it got slower, probably some query plan change or something like that.

Comment: Found the issue, apparently the application that the backups are done on did not inform the us that the backup was hung for a few days.  So They killed the backup and then everything started running fine.  Thank you all for your assistance.